# Android MediaRecorder creates video with unstable frame rate

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, frame-rate, video-recording

I'm trying to create videos of gameplay using MediaRecorder class, and I need to combine the video file with another video after recording is done. The problem is every video created by MediaRecorder has an unstable frame rate although I am setting it to 24, it always comes out with some other number like 39.542004 20.xxx etc, here is my code:

```
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outPutDir.getPath() + "/" + fileName);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(44100);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
```

I need my videos frame rate to be a stable 24 or 30 so I can append another video to it afterwards, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is some information on this in another post here: [Forcing the camera in Android to deliver 30 FPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375404/forcing-the-camera-in-android-to-deliver-30-fps)

Calling getSupportedPreviewFpsRange() will give you more information on what the range of the camera can be, and then set your suggested frame rate accordingly.

Note that requests to the hardware are often just suggestions. The camera automatically adjusts its frame rate as it accommodates for new lighting and focus settings. (more info on FPS adjustment here [Why does camera frame rate fluctuate when fusing another sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075337/why-does-camera-frame-rate-fluctuate-when-fusing-another-sensor))

Try dictating every camera setting so that the camera no longer makes automatic adjustments to better the quality of the picture, and see how the FPS is affected. Unfortunately, setting a specific FPS rate for the phone camera is unlikely to guarantee that FPS without also removing other variables that the camera changes.

Comment: Thanks Bailey, but I'm not using the device's camera here, I'm trying to record the surface (screen), I'm not sure if those camera restrictions still apply there